# reording kernel matrices

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I have an mxm kernel matrix, K, which is for the sake of simplicity, a linear kernel computed as pdist2(X,X), where X is mxn and the m dimension relates to feature vectors with n dimensions.

since n is large, I save computation time by precalculating K for all X.

Later on, I need to swap two of the features in X, say X_1 and X_5.

Can I somehow rearrange K, without having to recompute the entire matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `pv` is your permutation vector and `J0=pdist2(X,X)`, then

```
Y=X(pv,:); J1=pdist2(Y,Y);
```

should get you the same answer as

```
J1=J0(pv,pv);
```

If you are permuting the columns (I couldn't quite tell from your question), then it seems like `J1` and `J0` should be equal...